# JS Lightbox modal with pinch zoom

Tags: javascript, image, pinchzoom, viewer, html-framework-7

I need a JS Lightbox modal style image viewer with pinch to zoom gesture which should work with Framework7 (single-page web application style). It should open that modal by clicking on an img (like this )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) is exactly what i needed. Someone also implemented pinch to zoom. My question is answered.